# my viewcontroller does not fall in the viewdidLoad method

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a question, I am learning about programming in swift, I have learned to handle tables and collections without problems, including the cosumo of services with alamofire, but I face a problem, I have a collection within a personalized table view cell, the managed to do the event click inside the collection and I communicate it to the ViewController with a protocol passing information that I need, but when I load the following ViewController (TabsDetailProductViewController) it does not fall into the method on viewDidLoad if it does not jump to the ContentView that has added which is connected with the DetailProductContentViewController. That is, as I understood when using the method.

```
func ItemClick(position: Int, model: Product) {
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabsViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabsDetailProductViewController") as! TabsDetailProductViewController
        tabsViewController.productModel = model
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabsViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

I had to fall into the viewLoaded of the TabsDetailProductViewController but instead it jumps to the viewLoaded of the DetailProductContentViewController and then returns to the viewload of the TabsDetailProductViewController. I need to know what I'm doing wrong or maybe this is the life cycle.

This is my storyboard.

[image]

Comment: If you are going to "push" the view controller programmatically,  then remove the segue from the storyboard, this should be your first step, then debug more to see what else is going on

Comment: mmm you mean that segue that is in the image, the embed @MXNMike

Comment: good still the same, keep going directly to the DetailProductContentViewController , 
what I have been able to prove, is that when I remove the class to the DetailViewController from the storyboard, there is a first fall in the viewDidLoad of the TabsDetailProductViewController @MXNMike

Comment: ok so let me understand first what you are trying to accomplish here... the tabsViewcontroller handles the SegmentedController right? the segmented controller has a tableview and some row in the tableview has a collection view, is this correct?? then when you click on one of the collectionViewCells you open the detailsViewController? @dbenitobaldeon

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

`I need to know what I'm doing wrong`?

*Nothing*

`or maybe this is the life cycle.`

*Yes*

**Explanation**

According to Apple official documentation of [viewdidload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload)

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory.

In your case in order to completely load the `view hierarchy` of the `TabsDetailProductViewController` the `DetailProductContentViewController` has to be loaded first, as it is in the view hierarchy of `TabsDetailProductViewController` as a result of `containment`

Hence the `viewdidload` of `DetailProductContentViewController` will be called before  `TabsDetailProductViewController`'s `viewdidload`